# Facing issue while installing Package using package Manager console in Visual Studio for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget

While installing any package from Visual Studio using the Package Manager Console, I get an error - how to resolve it?

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.MVC
```

> Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.AspNet.MVC' at source ''.
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.MVC
> - 
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package],  Exception
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

In output window, it shows these messages:

> [Package source] Unable to load the service index for source https://packagesource.
>
> An error occurred while sending the request.
> The remote name could not be resolved: 'packagesource'

Comment: Check your NuGet client settings. You have an incorrectly configured package-source entry with a bogus URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the package source from the option.

Tool -> Option -> Nuget Package Manager

Add new source and add name as you want and in source for add **https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json**. and save it.

[image]