# Couldn't install "packageName" and "anotherPackageName"

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2022

I am switching to Visual Studio 2022 for .Net core 3.1 but Installer can't install two packages.
I tried uninstall and reinstall too much but it cannot resolve this problem.

Errors:

> Couldn't install Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Interop.Shared.Msi

> Couldn't install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SharedFramework.6.0.6.0.1-servicing.21567.14.x64

How can I fix it? Can you help me?

Deep Note: I'm using Windows 10 home single language.

Comment: Log message is turkish and too long. I can't share the log mssage

Comment: Please check this ,answer if you don't have added NuGet as package source https://stackoverflow.com/a/70503274/9787228

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem, my message code is 1911 (you can see on logs).

If you have same problem you can follow this way:

- Open Command prompt as administrator.
- Type "sfc /scannow".
- Reboot your computer when the process is complete.
- Repair the Visual Studio installation.